# How to reset environment variable in Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, ros, raspberry-pi4, raspberry-pi-os

I'm using ROS on Raspberry Pi 4(running Pi OS). I want to switch from one workspace to another so I edit the .bashrc file by commenting the original source command and adding the new source command to it.

But after restarting, I found out the $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH didn't get reset.(the old workspace directory still in it)

I searched online and found out that it seems RPi won't reset all the variable then source .bashrc file like normal terminal do.

So I'm wondering if there is anyway to reset all the environment variable.

Thank you~~

### Update to the first comment:

Environment variables don't persist through reboots?But everytime I reboot(cut the power then reconnect to power source), it seems to remember all the variable and my previos terminal command. Is this normal or something might be wrong?

Do you mean I need to copy all content from `.bashrc` to here?
The part I add in it is the command `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`

And by change workspace, I simply mean I create another workspace -> copy all the code I need into new worksapace's `src` -> and echo another source command `source ~/auv_ws/devel/setup.bash` into `.bashrc` ("auv_ws" is the name of my new workspace) & comment `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` -> source `.bashrc`

And since I source `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` before, the `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` already contained the path of the old workspace. So what I want to do is to get rid of it!

And I'm not sure if the other file like the one you mentioned had been modified before. Because actually I'm in a student team and I got the board from the previous teammates. If there is a way to check I'm willing to try and check.

Thanks a lot for your time~

### 2nd Update

This is my `.bashrc` file :

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
#[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w \$\[\033[00m\] '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
#alias ll='ls -l'
#alias la='ls -A'
#alias l='ls -CF'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

# Add Cython to PATH
export PATH="$PATH:/home/pi/.local/bin"

# Add miniconda3 to PATH
#export PATH="/home/pi/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"

export ROS_IP=192.168.0.140
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.0.140:11311

source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
source ~/auv_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

And the following is the `setup.bash` file of the old and new workspace(they are the same)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# generated from catkin/cmake/templates/setup.bash.in

CATKIN_SHELL=bash

# source setup.sh from same directory as this file
_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR=$(builtin cd "`dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"`" > /dev/null && pwd)
. "$_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR/setup.sh"
```

### 3rd Update

Below is the `setup.sh` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# generated from catkin/cmake/template/setup.sh.in

# Sets various environment variables and sources additional environment hooks.
# It tries it's best to undo changes from a previously sourced setup file before.
# Supported command line options:
# --extend: skips the undoing of changes from a previously sourced setup file
# --local: only considers this workspace but not the chained ones
# In plain sh shell which doesn't support arguments for sourced scripts you can
# set the environment variable `CATKIN_SETUP_UTIL_ARGS=--extend/--local` instead.

# since this file is sourced either use the provided _CATKIN_SETUP_DIR
# or fall back to the destination set at configure time
: ${_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR:=/home/pi/catkin_ws/devel}
_SETUP_UTIL="$_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR/_setup_util.py"
unset _CATKIN_SETUP_DIR

if [ ! -f "$_SETUP_UTIL" ]; then
  echo "Missing Python script: $_SETUP_UTIL"
  return 22
fi

# detect if running on Darwin platform
_UNAME=`uname -s`
_IS_DARWIN=0
if [ "$_UNAME" = "Darwin" ]; then
  _IS_DARWIN=1
fi
unset _UNAME

# make sure to export all environment variables
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
if [ $_IS_DARWIN -eq 0 ]; then
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
else
  export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
fi
unset _IS_DARWIN
export PATH
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
export PYTHONPATH

# remember type of shell if not already set
if [ -z "$CATKIN_SHELL" ]; then
  CATKIN_SHELL=sh
fi

# invoke Python script to generate necessary exports of environment variables
# use TMPDIR if it exists, otherwise fall back to /tmp
if [ -d "${TMPDIR:-}" ]; then
  _TMPDIR="${TMPDIR}"
else
  _TMPDIR=/tmp
fi
_SETUP_TMP=`mktemp "${_TMPDIR}/setup.sh.XXXXXXXXXX"`
unset _TMPDIR
if [ $? -ne 0 -o ! -f "$_SETUP_TMP" ]; then
  echo "Could not create temporary file: $_SETUP_TMP"
  return 1
fi
CATKIN_SHELL=$CATKIN_SHELL "$_SETUP_UTIL" $@ ${CATKIN_SETUP_UTIL_ARGS:-} >> "$_SETUP_TMP"
_RC=$?
if [ $_RC -ne 0 ]; then
  if [ $_RC -eq 2 ]; then
    echo "Could not write the output of '$_SETUP_UTIL' to temporary file '$_SETUP_TMP': may be the disk if full?"
  else
    echo "Failed to run '\"$_SETUP_UTIL\" $@': return code $_RC"
  fi
  unset _RC
  unset _SETUP_UTIL
  rm -f "$_SETUP_TMP"
  unset _SETUP_TMP
  return 1
fi
unset _RC
unset _SETUP_UTIL
. "$_SETUP_TMP"
rm -f "$_SETUP_TMP"
unset _SETUP_TMP

# source all environment hooks
_i=0
while [ $_i -lt $_CATKIN_ENVIRONMENT_HOOKS_COUNT ]; do
  eval _envfile=\$_CATKIN_ENVIRONMENT_HOOKS_$_i
  unset _CATKIN_ENVIRONMENT_HOOKS_$_i
  eval _envfile_workspace=\$_CATKIN_ENVIRONMENT_HOOKS_${_i}_WORKSPACE
  unset _CATKIN_ENVIRONMENT_HOOKS_${_i}_WORKSPACE
  # set workspace for environment hook
  CATKIN_ENV_HOOK_WORKSPACE=$_envfile_workspace
  . "$_envfile"
  unset CATKIN_ENV_HOOK_WORKSPACE
  _i=$((_i + 1))
done
unset _i

unset _CATKIN_ENVIRONMENT_HOOKS_COUNT
```

the only difference between auv_ws(new workspace) and catkin_ws(old workspace) are in line 14:
old: `: ${_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR:=/home/pi/catkin_ws/devel}`

new: `: ${_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR:=/home/pi/auv_ws/devel}`

Comment: Environment variables don't persist through reboots and you definitely don't want to unset all environment variables (your shell won't function without some of them). It's a bit difficult to follow exactly which order you're doing stuff in, especially since what you're describing is a result of you setting `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` somewhere. So, please update your question with the relevant parts of your `.bashrc` and the activation scripts (`setup.bash`?) and what's your procedure to change the workspace. Also, have you modified any other files, such as `/etc/profile`, `~/.profile` etc?

Comment: Environment variables don't persist through reboots?But everytime I reboot(cut the power then reconnect to power source), it seems to remember all the variable and my previos terminal command. Is this normal or something might be wrong?

Do you mean I need to copy all content from `.bashrc` to here? 
The part I add in it is the command `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`

Comment: And by change workspace, I simply mean I create another workspace -> copy all the code I need into new worksapace's `src` -> and echo another source command `source ~/auv_ws/devel/setup.bash` into `.bashrc` ("auv_ws" is the name of my new workspace) & comment `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` -> source `.bashrc`

And since I source `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` before, the `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` already contained the path of the old workspace. So what I want to do is to get rid of it!

Comment: And I'm not sure if the other file like the one you mentioned had been modified before. Because actually I'm in a student team and I got the board from the previous teammates. If there is a way to check I'm willing to try and check.

Thanks a lot for your time~

Comment: @frippe I found that the comment section is not really readable, so I put all my reply in the last part of my question.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, environment variables do not persist through reboots, but they are reset during boot, login and shell startup. Additional environment variables can be manually set, but unless they're put in one of the files that are sourced, they'll be gone after a reboot. As for the shell remembering the commands, it has a history file `.bash_history`.  You're saying that you're echoing a source command to the `.bashrc` - that makes me suspicious. Please share the part of your `.bashrc` that is related to ROS, too.

Comment: Also, update the question with the parts of `setup.bash` for your different workspaces where `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` gets set.

Comment: @frippe I've update the file in last part of question section. Sorry for the delay. Please have a look. Thank you~

Comment: Thanks, please paste that as text and not images next time. Two things, 1) you're sourcing both files in your `.bashrc` (you said that you commented one of them out), 2) We need the relevant part of the `setup.sh` (i.e., where `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` gets set) that is sourced on line 8 in the last image.

Comment: @frippe 1) the first "source" command is to source the whole ROS system not the old workspace. 2) OK I'll post it at the bottom of the question part.
But if I paste as text, the website will transform those command into its own format which will make the whole article messy.

Comment: Oh I found out how to paste in text form properly!! Sorry about the inconvenience!

Comment: I still can't find any traces of `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` that you're asking about. I wanted to rule out that `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` is appended to by those scripts (as opposed to reset). There's also the possibility that the new script somehow has been generated with the wrong `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`, but it's not possible to tell because you still haven't shown us the part where `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` gets set. Have you tried to just source the activation script in a terminal to see if the correct value of `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`?

Comment: Also, have you commented out both activation scripts for your ros workspaces to see if `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` is getting set somewhere else during shell initialization?